# Reactjs routes format needed

Tags: html, reactjs, routes, refresh

Asking here as I cannot find a definitive answer online..... Should my reactjs routes look like this

```
import './App.css'; import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Home from './components/Home';
import Test from './components/Test'; 
import Test1 from './components/Test1'; 

class App extends Component {
 render() { return
( 

<Router> 
<div> 
<Navbar /> 
<Switch> 
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> 
 <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} /> 
<Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
<Route exact path="/test1" component={Test1} /> 
<Route component={NoMatch} /> </Switch>
 </div> 
</Router> 
); 
} 
} 

export default App;
```

Or should it include index.html like this

```
<Route exact path="/test/index.html component={Test} />
```

The reason I ask is when I refresh the page on any path other than root I get a 404 page cannot be found

Comment: A 404 would be coming from your server, meaning that all routes are not being routed to the base react file. What's your server architecture?

Comment: Linux, Apache 2.2 with reactjs